# Need help for some query problems in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I get correct results for the following questions:

1. Query the top 3 grades across all subjects. Show the subject code, subject name, and the grade. Sort the grade in descending order. Repeating grades should not be displayed and should be considered as one.
2. Query the top 3 grades per subject. Show the subject code, subject name, and the grade. Sort the grade in descending order. Repeating grades should not be displayed and should be considered as one.
3. Query the top 3 grades per subject and show the student names. Show the subject code, subject name, student name, and the grade in descending order. NOTE: It is possible that students will have the same grades so you may have more than 3 results per subject if some students have the same grades and the grade belongs to the top 3.

**Data structure**

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/39b37/1)

Subject has a code and description. Student has a name. And grade has a link to a student, and subject and grade.

grade table

```
 grades_id|student_id|subject_id|grade
     1    |    1     |    1     |85
     2    |    1     |    2     |0
     3    |    1     |    3     |91
     4    |    1     |    4     |86
     5    |    1     |    5     |89
     6    |    1     |    6     |0
     7    |    2     |    1     |0
     8    |    2     |    2     |84
     9    |    2     |    3     |0
     10   |    2     |    4     |87
     11   |    2     |    5     |89
     12   |    2     |    6     |80
     13   |    3     |    1     |88
     14   |    3     |    2     |90
     15   |    3     |    3     |87
     16   |    3     |    4     |85
     17   |    3     |    5     |84
     18   |    3     |    6     |79
     19   |    4     |    1     |86
     20   |    4     |    2     |88
     21   |    4     |    3     |84
     22   |    4     |    4     |90
     23   |    4     |    5     |83
     24   |    4     |    6     |81
```

student table

```
student_id   | name
     1       | Samuel Canizares
     2       | Adrian Jacalan
     3       | Renan Villamor
     4       | Raymond Bongo
```

subject table

```
subject_id | subject_code | description
    1      |   122345     | Science
    2      |   113345     | Mathematics
    3      |   133445     | Religion
    4      |   111245     | English
    5      |   142355     | PE
    6      |   144521     | Social Studies
```

I am using PostgreSQL

here is my answer for question number 1:

```
select sb.subject_code,sb.description,gr.grade
from grade g inner join (select distinct on (grade) grade,grade_id from grade
) gr 
 on gr.grade_id = g.grade_id
 left join student st
    on st.student_id = g.student_id
left join subject sb
    on sb.subject_id = g.subject_id
 order by 3 desc limit 3
```

the problem is how can i get the top 3 grades per subject? i'm only limited to top grade across all subjects

Comment: You should post what you tried, it looks like homework....

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL?

Comment: Even I improved your question a lot, I do not think anyone will be motivated to do your homework. But I can offer some hints - you will need to read about [`distinct on`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) and probably also about [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html).

Comment: What have you already attempted when you worked on solving this yourself? Where are you stuck, what's confusing you about it? Which question are you stuck on (they're three separate problems)?

Comment: correction it is not homework it is just i'm curious how to solve it,the statement says that "Show the subject code, subject name, and the grade" is there a way to use "distinct on" in the 3rd column? cause i don't want to use the 1st column for the distinct grade

Comment: "*Repeating grades should not be displayed and should be considered as one*" (#1) is not clear to me. If different subjects have the same top grade (e.g. Mathematics and English) does that mean only one of those subjects should be sown (if yes, which one?)

Comment: Something like this should get you started: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/39b37/13

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i think only one of the subject should be shown because the questionnaire state that the repeating grades should be considered as one, it possible to show Mathematics and English with 90 and 89 grades? or is it impossible? just let me know

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i'm don't know how to use "dense_rank()" and "partition by" as much as possible i'll stick to the basics it seemed too advance for me

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i think you are right about that english and math should be shown,i think the problem states that it will only show the the top grades per subject but dont repeat top grades with the same subject

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i tried the sqlfiddle and it works like a charm, definitely solved my problem thank you but i found the dense_rank and partition by hard for me,i guess i have to study about this then cheers